# why the index.row recounting when I scroll the tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here, I want to using the index.row to index the Array, but weird thing is the index.row will recounting when I scroll the tableView. Is there have any solution? or another way to index the array?

Just like below:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
4 #recount from 4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Here is the source code:

```
func tableviewSetUp() {
    let rect = self.view.frame
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: rect)
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    self.tableView.register(WallpaperTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "wallpaperCell")
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "wallpaperCell", for: indexPath) as! WallpaperTableViewCell
    print(indexPath.row)  //here I print the row number
    let wallpaper = self.wallpaperIDList[indexPath.row]//here I using the index.row to index the array
    return cell
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}
```

Comment: Thats the core of cell reusing. Once a cell is scrolled off the screen it gets reused and has to be set up again when you scroll back.

Comment: @Sulthan Hmm, But this recount situation only occur once. After  recount from 4 the recount will never occur and count all the way down to 50.

Comment: @OttoYing: It should not matter how often and in which order the data source methods are called. If that affects your program then you have a programming error somewhere else.

Comment: At present it is unclear what your actual problem is...

Comment: Why is `numberOfRowsInSection` hardcoded with `50` when `cellForRowAt` is indexing `self.wallpaperIDList`? Your `numberOfRowsInSection` needs to return `self.wallpaperIDList.count`.

Answer (score 0):

Table views will call their data source methods as they see fit. you should not make any assumptions as to which IndexPaths will be passed to `tableView(cellForRowAt:)`. Just return cells when asked.

If it asks for row 4 twice, give it row 4 twice.

You **SHOULD** use an array as your data model. That is a very good way to represent the data for a single section table view. The fact that the table view is asking for the row at index 4 twice does not change that. (or use an array of arrays for a sectioned table view.)

Comment: Ok, who down-voted my answer? If you think my answer is poor, please explain why so I can improve it.

Answer (score -1):

The index row is not important no matter whether it's recounted or not. It doesn't affect the way tableview shows it's data. I have ran my code and the result as perfect as I expect.

Comment: Right. As I and several others have told you, you should not assume that the table view is going to ask for particular `IndexPath`s when it calls the `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` data source method. If it decides to ask for the same cell 20 times, you should just deliver the cell 20 times, and your code should not make assumptions about which cells it will request. Nor should you have side-effects from the data source methods being called.